# Neo4J browser: Unexpected behavior when saving list of strings as parameter

Tags: neo4j, cypher

In using the Neo4J browser UI, I encountered this strange behavior when trying to pass a list of strings as a parameter. (I was doing this so that I could query for nodes having a property value in the list.)

```
$ :param names: ["bob", "alice"]
$ RETURN $names = ["bob", "alice"]
```

This returns true, as expected.

```
$ :param nums: ["5", "22"]
$ RETURN $nums = ["5", "22"]
```

This returns **false**.

```
$ :param nums: ["5", "22"]
$ RETURN extract(x IN $nums | toString(x)) = ["5", "22"]
```

This returns **true**.

I don't understand why putting numbers in the strings requires the extra string conversion. Maybe it's a bug in how parameters are stored. Or am I just missing something?

Comment: What version of Neo4j are you using? Here `RETURN $nums = ["5", "22"]` returns true... I'm using Neo4j 3.2.1 CE.

Comment: I am using 3.1.1 CE of Neo4J. The browser UI reports version 2.0.0.

Comment: Every one of these is returning true for me in 3.2.1. Can you check each of those examples and make sure those are correct? I have a feeling you meant to use numbers rather than strings in the `$nums` param in the second example.

Comment: I'm 100% sure. I've just confirmed it again. Check this out: [screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/aNhOWdq.jpg)

Comment: I can confirm that working with either :param nums: [5, 22] or :param nums: ["5", "22"] returns true in version 3.2.2 CE. Must be a bug in 3.1.1.